# Is "to draw (out) money" related to getting credit or not?

Tags: meaning

examples from the internet:
**(1)** *He drew out the money*.
**(2)** *He drew out $200*.
**(3)** *He drew $100 from the bank*.

Do they mean A- or B-variant?

**(A-variant)**:

> He had the opportunity to take the money from his bank account and he did it.

**(B-variant)**:

> He did not have the opportunity to take the money from his bank account.
> He asked the bank provide him with such an opportunity.
> The bank agreed and gave him a credit.

Comment: You draw [out] money that you have deposited in an account. If there isn't enough money in there, your account is _overdrawn_. If the bank has agreed to this, it's an _arranged overdraft_.

Comment: You can draw  money from your bank account only if there is money available be it your own money or a credit you got from the bank.

Comment: I would make a distinction between 'money' and 'cash'. I have may have money of my own in my bank account; if the bank agrees to let me have credit, I have more money available and I could draw some out (or withdraw it) in cash. I can move money around from one account to another or send it to someone, all without seeing a single banknote.

Answer (score 1):

**The A variant**.

To draw money from an account is a fairly simple expression to understand. It simply means that you make a withdrawal from your account. The question of credit has nothing to do with it.

For example, suppose you have a credit facility of $1,000 on your account. That means you can let your bank balance get to negative $1,000 before the bank stops you.

1. If your balance is $500 you can draw out $200 and the balance is now $300.
2. If you then draw out another $400 dollars, your balance becomes negative $100 dollars.
3. If you then draw out $500 dollars, your balance has become negative $600.
4. Finally, if you then try to draw out $600 dollars more, the bank won't let you, because your balance would be negative $1,200 and that's over your credit limit.

But note that from an English language perspective it's exactly the same expression: *to **draw out money** from your account* (even in the last case where you couldn't draw it out.)